# Adding a UITabBarController and UITabs programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to add a UItabbar programmatically to a UIView. This is the code below, the app starts from a RootViewTableController, then gets pushed to this view, but the tabs don't work maybe it's something in MainWindow.xib that's the problem?:

```
//  TabBarController.h

@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController 
@end

//  TabBarController.m

#import "TabBarController.h"
#import "FirstV.h"

@implementation TabBarController

-(void)viewDidLoad {

NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc;

vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"A";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];
vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.title = @"B";
[listOfViewControllers addObject:vc];
[vc release];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers animated:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Screenshot here:
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see no tabs at the bottom, should I drag and drop a UItabbar element into the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `[super viewDidLoad];` **ABOVE** your code where it should be.